# Infinite loop in arm assembly

Tags: assembly, arm

My while loop is an infinite loop, and I don't understand why it doesn't break out.  It seems like r3 never gets incremented.  Am I missing something obvious?  cmp is supposed to subtract r5 from r3, which should equal 0 eventually and trigger beq, which should jump to addSum:

```
.section    .rodata
input:
.ascii "Enter number:\000"
output:
.ascii "Sum:%d\n\000"
inputformat:
.ascii "%d\000"

.section    .data
.align 4
.comm   intarray,20,4 /*allocates 20 bytes(4 bytes per int)*/
.comm   sum,4,4 /*allocates 4 bytes for an integer */
.comm   temp,4,4

.text
addrinput:
.word input
addroutput:
.word output
addrinputformat:
.word inputformat
addrintarray:
.word intarray
addrsum:
.word sum
addrtemp:
.word temp

.global main
main:
stmfd sp!, {r4,r5,fp,lr}
ldr r4,addrintarray
mov r3,#0
while:
mov r5,#5
cmp r5,r3
beq addSum
ldr r0,addrinput
bl printf
ldr r0,addrinputformat
ldr r1,addrtemp
bl scanf
mov r5,#1
add r3,r3,r5
bal while
addSum:
ldmfd sp!, {r4,r5,fp,pc}
```

Comment: `R3` is considered a scratch register in the [ARM ABI](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042e/IHI0042E_aapcs.pdf), meaning that `printf` may use it for its own purposes without preserving it. You can place `R3` on the stack temporarily when calling `printf`, or use `R4` instead of `R3` since you don't seem to be using `R4` for anything meaningful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot break out of infinite loop in ARM assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19441053/cannot-break-out-of-infinite-loop-in-arm-assembly)