# Cannot break out of infinite loop in ARM assembly

Tags: assembly, arm

I am writing a program that will add together 5 integers from stdin in ARM assembly, but I am reaching an infinite loop and have no idea why.

i start out by defining basic things

```
/*defines functions*/
    .section        .rodata
promptString:
     .ascii "Enter numbers: \000"
readString:
    .ascii "%d\000"
printSum:
    .ascii  "sum=%d\n\000"
/*global varibles*/
.section        .data
    .align 2

    .comm   string,4,4
    .text
/*sets addresses*/
addrString: .word string
addrPromptString:   .word promptString
addrReadString: .word readString
addrPrintSum:   .word printSum
```

I then start my main and have a loop that should last 5 iterations, but instead i reach an infinite loop

```
main:
    stmfd sp!, {fp, lr}
    mov r3,#0
    mov r2,#0
    mov r4,#5

loop:
    cmp r3,r4
    beq end

    ldr r0, addrPromptString
    bl  printf

    ldr r0, addrReadString
    ldr r1, addrString
    bl  scanf

    add r2,r2,r1
    add r3,r3,#1
    bl  loop
end:

    ldr  r2, addrPrintSum
    bl   printf

    ldmfd   sp!, {fp, pc}
```

By what i think is sound logic, it should jump to end when r3 reaches 5 and becomes equal to r4 which is 5.

But obviously it doesn't.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19440396/infinite-loop-in-arm-assembly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming printf and scanf are C functions, your r2 and r3 register values might be getting clobbered. The ARM ABI uses these registers as temporary registers when not being used as function parameters, so they are not guaranteed to be saved by the functions you call.

However, the ABI expects r4 through r11 to be saved before they are used. So your code might work if you save, say, r4 through r6 in the stack, use r5 and r6 in place of r2 and r3, and restore r4 through r6 when returning. That way, you follow the ABI and printf and scanf won't interfere with your variables.

Also, where it says "bl loop", you need to replace that with "b loop", so it isn't always setting the link register to the location of "end".

Comment: I changed my code according you what you said, and no the infinite loop is gone, but it immediately achieved a segmentation fault upon entering the 5th integer.

Comment: You should update your code in the question then, most people here don't own a crystal ball. ;)

Comment: I noticed after the loop, you don't set r0 and r1 for printf, so their values are ambiguous. Also, what you set for r2 belongs in r0, the first parameter in printf, and r1 should be the sum you expect to print out.

Comment: Also, after scanf, you need to load the value from address "string" before you add to the sum. Even assuming r1 isn't clobbered by scanf or its callees, you are just adding the address of it to the sum.